# Including a single javascript file on multiple domains

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have multiple domains with multiple copies of jQuery.js in separate subfolders.  I want to consolidate them so there's only one, and so there's no reference in one domain to another so I can use the same one for work and personal.

Furthermore, I don't want to use symbolic links because I'll be moving servers sometime this year and I feel that a lot of symlinks could complicate things.  One idea I had was instead of this in the HTML:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to do this:

```
<script src="jquery_min_js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And that file will look like this:

```
<?php echo '/home/path/to/js_files/js/jquery.min.js' ?>
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?  I'd like to somehow make a function so like

```
<script src="get_javascript.php?script=jquery_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then get_javascript.php might look like:

```
<?php echo '/home/path/to/js_files/js/'.str_replace('_','.',$_GET['script']).'.js' ?>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?   Am I even in the right forest?

Comment: why not just use google code? http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One idea is to include from google code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3 reasons why:

http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: Better still `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can link to jQuery from either Google or Microsoft.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

### or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">`</script>
```